# fetching data from json file in js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to fetch data from an external json file called comuni.json, here it is a preview:

```
[
    {
      "codice": "A001",
      "comune": "ABANO TERME",
      "provincia": "PD"
    },
    {
      "codice": "A004",
      "comune": "ABBADIA CERRETO",
      "provincia": "LO"
    }
]
```

My goal is to get the `"codice"` value of the respective `"provincia"` element. What I mean is that if the user type **PD** the script gets **A001**. However if the user type *LO* the script gets *A004*. I hope I express myself well.

My script looks like this:

```
const jsonfile = require('./comuni.json');
var data = JSON.parse(jsonfile)
var i;
for (i in data){
  if (data[txt_placeBirthday]instanceof Object){
    let codice_castale = data[txt_placeBirthday]['codice']
    return codice_castale
  }
}
```

However I don't know how to proceed, I searched online but nothing really helped. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by find() method.

```js
const inputValue = "PD"

const dataBackFromApi = [
    {
      "codice": "A001",
      "comune": "ABANO TERME",
      "provincia": "PD"
    },
    {
      "codice": "A004",
      "comune": "ABBADIA CERRETO",
      "provincia": "LO"
    }
]

const codice = dataBackFromApi.find(ele => ele.provincia === inputValue)?.codice

console.log(codice)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). This allows you get the first match that matches your test, in this case matching `provincia` to a value. If no match was found it returns `undefined` so you can either test for `undefined` or use [`?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
const data = [
    {
      "codice": "A001",
      "comune": "ABANO TERME",
      "provincia": "PD"
    },
    {
      "codice": "A004",
      "comune": "ABBADIA CERRETO",
      "provincia": "LO"
    }
];

const result = data.find(item => item.provincia === "PD");

if (result !== undefined) {
  console.log(result.codice);
} else {
  console.error('Could not find ...');
}

// or

console.log(result?.codice);
```